# 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then") in my script

Tags: shell, syntax, syntax-error, sh, netcat

Hello i have a problem in this script 
This feature is apparently bad but how to fix it?

```
nc -z -v ip adress port
if connect to ip adress port 13000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
then
cd /usr/home/game/
./game
else
exit
fi
```

error :

5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `if connect to ip adress port 13000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`? Is there really a command `connect` that takes these parameters? Or are you trying to check for an error?

Comment: Do you intend to run `./game` only if the `nc` command *fails*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result=$(nc -z -v $ipaddress $port 2>&1)
if [ "$result" = "connect to ip adress port 13000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused" ]
then
    cd /usr/home/game
    ./game
else
    exit
fi
```

`$(...)` substitutes the output of the command into the command line. And `2>&1` redirects standard error to standard output, so the error message will be captured by this.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably just act based on the exit status of nc:

```
if nc ...
then
    play the game
else
    exit
fi
```